Why doesn't Conjugate[] conjugate exponentials inside other functions?
Why does something like Conjugate[Sqrt[Exp[I  x]]] give output Conjugate[Sqrt[E^(I x)]] instead of Sqrt[E^(-I x)]?
In some places I get outputs such as: Conjugate[0.752066  E^((3 I \[Pi])/2 - (0. + 3.46164 I) x - x^2/2)]. Why does this happen?

Use ESC+e+e+ESC for e and ESC+i+i+ESC for i.

Or use Exp[I]

Use Exp[ ] for exponential function and (capital) I for the imaginary unit. Conjugate[Exp[I]] correctly returns Exp[-I] as expected.

I use ESC+e+e+ESC and the same for i. I only wrote like that for simplicity. Exp[I] works on its own, but not inside other functions. But still I was not aware of it thank you for pointing it out.

I see your point. Then, the last sentence “why Conjugate[] can't(or won't) conjugate Exp[I]” is misleading….

@A.Kato you are right. I will edit my question accordingly.

Do any of these help?
Complex $x$:
ComplexExpand[Conjugate[Sqrt[E^(I  x)]], x] // FullSimplify
(*  E^(-(Im[x]/2))/Sqrt[E^(I Re[x])]  *)

Real $x$:
ComplexExpand[Conjugate[Sqrt[E^(I  x)]]] // FullSimplify
(*  1/Sqrt[E^(I x)]  *)

Complex $x$:
PowerExpand[Conjugate[Sqrt[E^(I  x)]], Assumptions -> True]
(*  E^(-(1/2) I Conjugate[x] + I π Floor[1/2 - Re[x]/(2 π)])  *)

Real $x$:
PowerExpand[Conjugate[Sqrt[E^(I  x)]], 
 Assumptions -> x \[Element] Reals]
(*  E^(-((I x)/2) + I π Floor[1/2 - x/(2 π)])  *)


Mathematically speaking, conjugation of a function $\bar{f}(z)$ is not necessarily same as the same function evaluated at the conjugate argument $f(\bar{z})$. As an example, if $f(z)=z+i$, clearly $\bar{f}(z)\ne f(\bar{z})$. Therefore, Mathematica cannot replace $\bar{e}(z)$ with $e(\bar{z})$ if $e$ is undefined, which is why Conjugate[e^i] does not evaluate to something simpler
In case of Exp[x], Mathematica does realize that exponential is a function which obeys Schwarz Reflection Principle, hence evaluates Conjugate[Exp[f[x]]] to Exp[Conjugate[f[x]]].

There are outputs in my code that are of the form Conjugate[E^(0+0.37294 I)].

@EFETÜRBEDAR Why didn't you add this concrete example  Conjugate[E^(0+0.37294 I)] in your question?

@UlrichNeumann I really should have. I wiill fix my question.


Why does something like Conjugate[Sqrt[Exp[I  x]]] give output
Conjugate[Sqrt[E^(I x)]] instead of Sqrt[E^(-I x)]?

Because the two are not equivalent, for example:
{Conjugate[Sqrt[Exp[I x]]], Sqrt[E^(-I x)]} /. x -> 1 + I
FunctionExpand[%]
N[%%]


{Conjugate[Sqrt[E^(-1 + I)]], Sqrt[E^(1 - I)]}

{E^(-(1/2) - I/2), E^(1/2 - I/2)}

{0.532281 - 0.290786 I, 1.44689 - 0.790439 I}


Ok but they are the same when x is not complex, and even when it is shouldn't it output Sqrt[Exp[-I Conjugate[x]]] ? Also even after putting in values for x, I am left with expressions that have Conjugate[] in them.

@EFETÜRBEDAR "Also even after putting in values for x, I am left with expressions that have Conjugate[] in them." Use FunctionExpand afterwards like I did in my answer. Then maybe use also ComplexExpand if needed.
